# Determining projected coordinate system for area in Italy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, italy

I am working in ArcGIS and I have calculated the slope which shows higher values which is unusual. I came to know about projected coordinates system. I am working on a lake located in Italy.

Which projected coordinate system should I use for Italy?

I obtained elevation data from DEM downloaded from STRM 90 m resolution.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @MichaelStimson:

> SRTM is in WGS84 Geographic (EPSG:4326), that would give you some very
> bad slopes as the horizontal distance is in decimal degrees where 1 is
> a very large distance. Most of Italy is either in UTM zone 33 north
> (EPSG:32633) or zone 32 north (EPSG:32632).